# How do I prevent placeholder text from being vertically centered in a large height input form element?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, less

Placeholder text in a `input type='text'`  element with a height of `100px` is vertically centered. I want it aligned on the **top**.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5u83oL78/)

[image]

`Product.html`

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label for="description">Description</label>
            <input type="text" name="description" id="description" placeholder="Enter a new product description..." class="form-control" />
</div>
```

`product.less`

```
#description{
  height: 100px;

  ::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
    vertical-align: top;
  }
  ::-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 19+ */
    vertical-align: top;
  }
  :-ms-input-placeholder { /* IE 10+ */
    vertical-align: top;
  }
  :-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
    vertical-align: top;
  }
}
```

I have fiddled with taking the psuedo selectors out of the `#description` block so they aren't compiled to `#description ::-webkit...` but that didn't work. I have tried all types of combinations of vertical-align and can't figure it out. Maybe the placeholder psuedo selector isn't the right path? We're using bootstrap but I can't find anything that would cause it to force a vertical align in a placeholder, or any bootstrappy way to achieve a top-aligned placeholder text.

EDIT: There are no LESS compile errors. I have confirmed the psuedo-selectors are being compiled into the `.css` files.

EDIT: I had a brain fart and was trying to build a big text area the hard way. [Textareas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea) exist, use those if you have found yourself here.

Comment: JSfiddle please. (for me, CSS is better, but you don't need to).

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5u83oL78/ thank you

Comment: Note that the reason I asked this is because I had a tremendous brainfart and forgot that `textarea`s exist https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea Chances are if you're trying to do what I just did, you're better off using a `textarea`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this :

**:placeholder-shown** is for selecting the input itself when it's placeholder text is being shown. As opposed to **::placeholder** which styles the placeholder text.

```
#description{
  height: 100px; 
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
    position: relative !important;
    transform:translateY(-220%) !important;
    color:red !important;
  }
  input::-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 19+ */
    vertical-align: top;
  }
  input::-ms-input-placeholder { /* IE 10+ */
    vertical-align: top;
  }
```

In my code this pseudo-element started to respond to our styling only with !important.

https://jsfiddle.net/5u83oL78/2/

Comment: I accepted this answer because it answers the question - "align the placeholder text to the top" rather than add padding. However, note that unlike Ibrahim's answer, the input area itself remains in the middle, which is probably not what someone would want.

Answer (score 3):

Use padding:

```
input.form-control {
   padding: 0px 12px 60px 12px;
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/5u83oL78/3/

Comment: that's pushing from bottom, but not actually aligning to top.

Comment: I accepted the other answer because technically this doesn't align at the top, but uses hardcoded pixel values to push to the top. However, this method also pushes up the input area itself, so input text appears top-aligned as well. That looks better than the other answer.

Comment: @komali_2 No worries. I voted up the other answer too.